# How to make this notch like design using html, css or tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, clip-path

[image]

I need to make this design.

I used this clip-path method but the edges is not smooth. how can i achieve the design?

```
.nav {
    width: 14rem;
    height: 4rem;
    background-color: white;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 70% 100%, 30% 100%);
}
```

Comment: Did you want this with tailwind classes or no?

Comment: Either is fine, use your preference. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried creating a png file with that notch design and using that?

Answer (score 1):

It's  hard to do this with *polygon*. You could try to add more points (a lot more) but the result might not be perfect.
Much better result would be with *path* property but it's not fully supported yet (https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path).

I would go for **SVG background** or **box-shadow**.

If you could export path as an svg from your design source file it would be the fastest way ;) If not you can always try to draw it for yourself (e.g. in Inkscape).

For *box-shadow* approach you would have to do 4 divs with custom made shadows (2 on the left and 2 on the right side of the 'notch'). Here you can check how to make curved shape as box-shadow: https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/#aa-reverse-corners-via-zberno.